# Display for a specific WooCommerce product attribute the terms list on a page

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, taxonomy-terms

In Woocommerce, I am trying to create a simple page with all brands that I have from product attribute `pa_brand`. But I didn't find the correct way to make that.

So this page needs to show linked brands names as a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a custom shortcode function that will output the linked term names list for "pa_brand" product attribute. It can be used in any page or post using the Wordpress content text editor or in php code:

```
add_shortcode( 'product_attribute_list', 'shortcode_product_attribute_list' );
function shortcode_product_attribute_list( $atts ) {
    // Shortcode Attributes
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'taxonomy'    => 'pa_brand',
        'orderby'     => 'name',
        'hide_empty'  => false, 
    ), $atts, 'product_attribute_list' );

    $terms = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy'      => $atts['taxonomy'],
        'orderby'       => $atts['orderby'],
        'hide_empty'    => $atts['hide_empty'], 
    ) );

    $html = '<ul class="' . $atts['taxonomy'] . ' brands">';

    // Loop through the taxonomy terms
    foreach( $terms as $term ){
        $html .= '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $term, $atts['taxonomy'] ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
    }

    return $html . '</ul>'; // Return the output
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

**USAGE example:**

1) Inside a Page or post content text Editor *(or a text widget)*:

```
[product_attribute_list]
```

2) On a php template or code:

```
echo do_shortcode("[product_attribute_list]");
```

You will only need to add some CSS rules to your active theme's styles.css file to get the desired design.

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Can you hide a attribute that only contains products that are out of stock? Since If you have a product that is out of stock it dosen't count as a empty attribute.